# call other function in geocomplete

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I use the method geocomplete to individualize the coordinates of an address.

```
$("#geocomplete2").geocomplete({
     details: "#register"

    });
```

I would want to know if it is possible to the inteno of the function to recall one function of mine

```
$("#geocomplete2").geocomplete({
     details: "#register"
     CALL MY FUNCTION DEMO
    });


    function demo(value) {
   alert(value);
   }
```

is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs

```
$("input")
  .geocomplete()
  .bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
    console.log(result);
  });
```

In your case:

```
$("#geocomplete2").geocomplete({
    details: "#register"
}).bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
    demo(result)
});


function demo(value) {
    alert(value);
}
```